# div with an image and link to download selected image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I would like to see the image when I download to desk top. i can convert the div into an image with the image of the dog bu i cant seem to be able to download the image with the dog image in it. why would that happen? can someone please help me find a solution here is a live view http://torcdesign.com/banana/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#imajes').change(function() {
    $('.subselector').hide();
    $('.smallimages').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
 
  });
  
    $('.smallimages').hide();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).val();
 
 
$('#dog').on('change', function() {
  
  $("#bulldogimges").css('display', (this.value == 'bulldog') ? 'block' : 'none');


   $("#huntingdogimges").css('display', (this.value == 'huntingdog') ? 'block' : 'none');
   $("#germandogimges").css('display', (this.value == 'policedog') ? 'block' : 'none');
});

$('img').on('click', function() {
    $('#fotos').append('<div class="imgdrag"><img class="modal-content" src="' + $(this).attr('src')+ '"/></div>'); $('.imgdrag').draggable();
$('#fotos').droppable();
            $('.modal-content').resizable();



});

  
  
});


var download = document.getElementById("download"),
  result = document.getElementById("previewImage");

function renderContent() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("firstshirt"), {
        allowTaint: true
    }).then(function(canvas) {
      result.appendChild(canvas);
        download.style.display = "inline"; download.href = result.children[0].toDataURL();
    });
}

function downloadImage() {
  
}

document.getElementById("btn-Preview-Image").onclick = renderContent;
download.onclick = downloadImage
```

```css
.container {background-color: transparent;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: relative;
overflow: hidden;

/* Will stretch to specified width/height */
  background-size: 490px 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://hongru.github.io/proj/canvas2image/canvas2image.js"></script>

<script  
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Philosopher' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://files.codepedia.info/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js"></script>

<select id="imajes">
        <option value="">Choose Image</option>
        
        <option value="dog">Dog</option>
        
    </select> 

<select id="dog" name="subselector" class="subselector" style="display:none">
  <option value="">Choose an item</option>
  <option value="bulldog">Bulldog</option>
  <option value="huntingdog">Hunting Dog</option>
  <option value="policedog">German Shepherd</option>
</select>
<div id="firstshirt" class="container" style="float:left;"><div id="fotos" ><img class="modal-content" id="imgdisplay" /></div></div>
<input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/><a id="download" download="my_image.png" href="#">Download image</a>
<h3>result:</h3>
<div> <div id="previewImage">
    </div><a id="download" download="my_image.png" href="#">Download image</a></div>
    
    <div style='display:none;' id="bulldogimges" class="smallimages">
<div class="imgcontainerss" data-image="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/pT78gE6pc.gif">
    <img src="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/pT78gE6pc.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>
<div class="imgcontainerss" data-image="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/LiKkRqkeT.gif">
    <img src="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/LiKkRqkeT.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>
<div class="imgcontainerss" data-image="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/free-bulldog-clipart-031350.gif">
    <img src="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/free-bulldog-clipart-031350.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: your downloadImage() method is a null implementation. It not contains any statements in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check updated code:

I have updated download image button code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#imajes').change(function() {
    $('.subselector').hide();
    $('.smallimages').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
 
  });
  
    $('.smallimages').hide();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).val();
 
 
$('#dog').on('change', function() {
  
  $("#bulldogimges").css('display', (this.value == 'bulldog') ? 'block' : 'none');


   $("#huntingdogimges").css('display', (this.value == 'huntingdog') ? 'block' : 'none');
   $("#germandogimges").css('display', (this.value == 'policedog') ? 'block' : 'none');
});

$('img').on('click', function() {
    $('#fotos').append('<div class="imgdrag"><img class="modal-content" src="' + $(this).attr('src')+ '"/></div>'); $('.imgdrag').draggable();
$('#fotos').droppable();
            $('.modal-content').resizable();


$(".download").attr("href",$(this).attr('src'));
  $(".download").show();
});

  
  
});


var download = document.getElementById("download"),
  result = document.getElementById("previewImage");

function renderContent() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("firstshirt"), {
        allowTaint: true
    }).then(function(canvas) {
      result.appendChild(canvas);
        download.style.display = "inline"; download.href = result.children[0].toDataURL();
    });
}

function downloadImage() {
  
}

document.getElementById("btn-Preview-Image").onclick = renderContent;
download.onclick = downloadImage
```

```css
.container {background-color: transparent;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: relative;
overflow: hidden;

/* Will stretch to specified width/height */
  background-size: 490px 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.download{
display:none;  

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://hongru.github.io/proj/canvas2image/canvas2image.js"></script>

<script  
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Philosopher' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://files.codepedia.info/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js"></script>

<select id="imajes">
        <option value="">Choose Image</option>
        
        <option value="dog">Dog</option>
        
    </select> 

<select id="dog" name="subselector" class="subselector" style="display:none">
  <option value="">Choose an item</option>
  <option value="bulldog">Bulldog</option>
  <option value="huntingdog">Hunting Dog</option>
  <option value="policedog">German Shepherd</option>
</select>
<div id="firstshirt" class="container" style="float:left;"><div id="fotos" ><img class="modal-content" id="imgdisplay" /></div></div>
<input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/><a class="download" id="download" download="my_image.png" href="#">Download image</a>
<h3>result:</h3>
<div> <div id="previewImage">
    </div><a id="download" class="download" download="my_image.png" href="#">Download image</a></div>
    
    <div style='display:none;' id="bulldogimges" class="smallimages">
<div class="imgcontainerss" data-image="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/pT78gE6pc.gif">
    <img src="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/pT78gE6pc.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>
<div class="imgcontainerss" data-image="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/LiKkRqkeT.gif">
    <img src="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/LiKkRqkeT.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>
<div class="imgcontainerss" data-image="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/free-bulldog-clipart-031350.gif">
    <img src="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/free-bulldog-clipart-031350.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: it works but once i insert it with the rest of my stuff i still get a blank img

Comment: here is a URL so you can see what im talking about very sorry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435701/converting-div-with-other-images-inside-into-image?noredirect=1#comment70077430_41435701

Comment: You need to assign href to download link. Above question is on hold. So I am not able to answer it.